# Will Unity fix the plugin issues with Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, unity-game-engine

As you may be aware, Chrome dropped support for NPAPI-based plugins, giving at least a year for affected software, like Unity, to switch away. Unity unfortunately didn't do so, and so recently the support on Chrome is dropped and we end users have to find our own workarounds. I heard that Mozilla is going in that direction too. Does anyone know if the folks at Unity are working towards a long-term solution, or is Unity effectively killed? I haven't been able to find anything official from the Unity team yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Unity Web Browser** plugin is **dead** and will be **buried** when **Firefox** removes support of NPAPI, which will happen soon. The **funeral** of **Unity Browser plugin** will be held when **Firefox** removes support of **NPAPI**.

The **solution** to your problem is to download **Unity 5** and compile your Game using **WebGL** from the **Build Settings**. The **WebGL** is the replacement of NPAPI and is also compatible with most web browsers. NPAPI will be considered a legacy technology very soon.

Comment: You should be careful to distinguish between fact and opinion in answers. I've never seen any specific statement from Mozilla about when they plan to fully remove NPAPI support, so saying that it will happen "soon" as if it were a fact is potentially misleading.